# Max iterations (100) reached for batch Resolution

Tags: databricks

I am using spark sql in databricks notebook, its lengthy query. It throws below error

org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Max iterations (100) reached for batch Resolution, please set 'spark.sql.analyzer.maxIterations' to a larger value.

I set

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.optimizer.maxIterations",200);
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.analyzer.maxIterations",200);

based on some stackoverflow suggestions I also tried

spark.sql("set spark.sql.optimizer.maxIterations = 200");
spark.sql("set spark.sql.analyzer.maxIterations = 200");

its not working. Any help on this appreciated.

Comment: I tried diffrent larger values > 10000 still its not working , does the notebook consider the value I set ? is there an other way to set these parameters ? below is the way i set these configs                             
 spark.conf.set("spark.sql.optimizer.maxIterations",10000);
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.analyzer.maxIterations",10000);

Comment: may be show some code

Comment: This has been fixed, some configs needs to be set while creating the cluster in databricks, so while creating the cluster *advanced options -> spark -> spark config*    here set the below configs                                              spark.sql.analyzer.maxIterations 10000
spark.sql.optimizer.maxIterations 10000